# invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

I'm working on the following homework problem from [C for Scientists and Engineers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0077290461):

```
Given the following declarations and assignments, what do these expressions evaluate to?

int a1[10] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}
int *p1, *p2;
p1 = a1+3;
Line 14: p2 = *a1[2];
```

I'm trying to compile this code with gcc, but when I do so, it gives me the following error:

```
w03_3_prob15.c: In function 'main':
w03_3_prob15.c:14:7: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
```

I'm using the following command to compile:

```
gcc -o w03_3_prob15 w03_3_prob15.c -std=c99
```

I'm really not sure what to do. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this error?

Comment: You are not meant to compile it to do the homework. You should be able to look at it and know the answer. But the code you post is broken. Go back to the book and check you typed it correctly.

Comment: I just checked that I typed the code accurately from the book, and I did. Note that 'Line 14: ' was added to show where the error is located.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line doesn't compile because it's incorrect in the book.  From the [author's Errata page](http://iel.ucdavis.edu/cfores/errata.php):

```
Page 438, line 17 from the bottom.
p2 = *a1[2]; 
should be  p2 = &a1[2];
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks for pointing that out that page to me. That will come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
p2 = *a1[2];
```

In C, unary `*` is only defined for pointers. `p2` is an `int*`. `a1` is an `int[]`. `a1[2]` is an `int`. `[]` has higher precedence than unary `*`, so you have `*(a1[2])`, which is not a legal expression. This is why the compiler is halting.

I can think of two possible solutions for this. Which one you want, depends on what you are trying to do.

```
*p2 = a1[2]; // Assigns the value of the second int in the array to the location
             // pointed to by p2.
p2 = &a1[2]; // Assigns the location of the second int in the array to p2.
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of `p2` is `int*`.  The type of `a1[2]` is `int`, so `*a1[2]` is meaningless.  Are you sure you copied the homework problem exactly?  (If so, bad homework problem.  They happen.)